# how to put a valid filepath as a function parameter in python

Tags: python, filepath

I am trying to write a save/load function for a text based game in python 3.5.1, and I found some helpful code on this site, unfortunately, both functions just need a file path as one of the parameters. I am learning python as I go and am relatively new to both this site and coding in general, so help on how to enter in a valid file path (and examples of what a valid file path is in this case!) would be greatly appreciated (once again, I'm like Jon Snow). The relevant methods are posted below:

```
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.maxHealth = 100
    self.health = self.maxHealth
    self.baseAttack = 10
    self.credits = 10
    self.augs = 0
    self.weap = ["Basic Nanite Pack"]
    self.currWeap = ["Basic Nanite Pack"]
    global playerFile
    playerFile = {"name":self.name, "health":self.maxHealth, "maxHealth":self.health, "baseAttack":self.baseAttack,
                  "weapon":self.weap, "currWeap":self.currWeap, "credits":self.credits, "augs":self.augs}

def saveGame(playerFile, filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'w') as outfile:
        for name,num in playerFile.items():
            outfile.write("{};{};\n".format(num, name))

import csv
def loadGame(filepath):
    with open(filepath) as infile:
        # purposeful misspell for variable name
        playerFil = dict((v,k) for v,k,_ in csv.reader(infile, delimiter=';'))
    return playerFil
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file path is a path to a file from start to end.
e.g c:\users\John\my_document.txt

This is a valid file path and you should normally pass it like this:

```
r'c:\users\John\my_document.txt'
```

Note that if you dont give a path for an actual file 
e.g c:\users\John 
Python won't be able to open any file since that would be a directory path.